# How to keep object fixed to bottom of screen on Chrome on iOS during Find Function?

Tags: html, css

I've got an object that has a fixed position on bottom of screen CSS that is behaving strangely on Chrome iOS when finding on page using the browser function. If you try to find text using "Find on page" function, and then scroll while finding, the keyboard moves down and then element gets stuck in the middle of page (as if the keyboard is still there). It's got a bit of strange gravity, if you scroll up the element will stick back to the bottom, but if you scroll down it will float back to the centre.

Object is an anchor link, that is used to turn to the Contents/Navigation section for the page.

I'm hoping there might be a solution for some specific styling targeting Chrome when the find function is used, or by setting some !important css setting that override whatever Chrome is doing when Finding.

I can't reproduce on desktop, via inspector. It seems to be a virtual keyboard thing.

I haven't been able to work out any fix, as it's unexpected behaviour, and I haven't been able to locate documentation that would like me target Chrome on iOS during the find function.

HTML

```
<nav id="TOP-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#TOC-anchor"><span>Return to</span> <span>Table</span> <span>of Contents</span>
      </a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar_left nav#TOP-nav {
    position: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url(../image/bg_ribbon_separator.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    z-index: 99;
    font-family: "Inknut Antiqua",serif;
    font-weight: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
#sidebar_left nav#TOP-nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I expect the object to stay at the bottom of the screen, but the find function remains in the middle.

Comment: can you create a fiddle or code pen with your workaround.

Comment: I've been able to get the fixed footer to work on code pen. It works as expected on desktop preview, but on mobile devices the footer doesn't stay fixed :https://codepen.io/JasonKotzur/pen/ROwPqV Here's the actual live project: http://root.livingrules.io/

Comment: I've been able to get the fixed footer to work on code pen. It works as expected on desktop preview, but on mobile devices the footer doesn't stay fixed :https://codepen.io/JasonKotzur/pen/ROwPqV Here's the actual live project: http://root.livingrules.io/